# How convert a long to int in Java vs. swift?

Tags: java, swift

I have try to convert this code in Java to swift 2.0

```
long checksumValue = 4253726258L;
int liCrc32 = (int)checksumValue;
System.out.println("liCrc32" + liCrc32)
```

LiCrc32 is equal to -41241038

My swift version

```
let int64: Int64 = 4253726258
let a:Int = Int(int64)
```

a returns me 4253726258

What i don't understand why in Java the value is negative?

Comment: The number is too big to fit into a java ``int``. Why do you cast it to ``int``? Use ``long`` all the way.

Comment: Tks. I willl do that !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a wrong type: Swift's `Int` does not necessarily match Java's `int`, because its size is platform-specific. Judging from your output, your platform uses 64-bit `Int`s. Here is how to confirm this:

```
println(sizeof(Int)) // Should print 8 on your platform
```

`Int32` matches Java's `int`. Unfortunately, this change

```
let int64: Int64 = 4253726258
let a:Int32 = Int32(int64)
```

may cause issues due to a bug in Swift's implementation.

If you need to sign-extend a 32-bit value, you can do it like this:

```
let int64: Int64 = 4253726258
let a:Int = Int((int64 << 32) >> 32)
println(a) // prints -41241038
```

[Demo.](http://swiftstub.com/857613118/?v=gm)

Comment: I am curious: What *bug* are your speaking of? –  `let a = Int32(truncatingBitPattern: int64)` should work correctly in any case.

Comment: @MartinR I pasted the two-line code snippet into [http://www.runswiftlang.com/](http://www.runswiftlang.com/), and got a crash with an invalid instruction: `94909 Illegal instruction: 4` I got the same result pasting the code at [http://swiftstub.com/](http://swiftstub.com/), except they "mask" the error with a message that they think sounds funny (it doesn't).

Comment: I don't think that is a bug. The `Int32(_ v: Int64)` constructor does not truncate implicitly (and aborts in the case of an overflow), in contrast to `Int32(truncatingBitPattern v: Int64)`.

Comment: @MartinR Producing an illegal instruction trap is always a compiler bug, even when the program is supposed to crash with an exception.

Answer (score 8):

From the [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

> **`Int`**
>
> In most cases, you don’t need to pick a specific size of integer to
>   use in your code. Swift provides an additional integer type, Int,
>   which has the same size as the current platform’s native word size:
>
> - On a 32-bit platform, `Int` is the same size as `Int32`.
> - **On a 64-bit platform, `Int` is the same size as `Int64`.**
>
> Unless you need to work with a specific size of integer, always use
>   `Int` for integer values in your code. This aids code consistency and
>   interoperability. Even on 32-bit platforms, Int can store any value
>   between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647, and is large enough for many
>   integer ranges.

[Java's `int`, on the other hand, is always 4 bytes.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)

> The integral types are `byte`, `short`, **`int`**, and `long`, whose values are
>   8-bit, 16-bit, **32-bit** and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers,
>   respectively, [...]

Casting from a `long` to an `int` causes a [narrowing primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)

> A narrowing primitive conversion may lose information about the
>   overall magnitude of a numeric value and may also lose precision and
>   range.

Comment: This answer is very useful 

Answer (score 2):

> **int:** By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -231 and a maximum
>   value of 231-1. In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the int data type
>   to represent an unsigned 32-bit integer, which has a minimum value of
>   0 and a maximum value of 232-1. Use the Integer class to use int data
>   type as an unsigned integer. See the section The Number Classes for
>   more information. Static methods like compareUnsigned, divideUnsigned
>   etc have been added to the Integer class to support the arithmetic
>   operations for unsigned integers.
>
> **long:** The long data type is a 64-bit two's complement integer. The signed long has a minimum value of -263 and a maximum value of 263-1.
>   In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the long data type to represent an
>   unsigned 64-bit long, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum
>   value of 264-1. Use this data type when you need a range of values
>   wider than those provided by int. The Long class also contains methods
>   like compareUnsigned, divideUnsigned etc to support arithmetic
>   operations for unsigned long.

Meaning that an int in Java < J8 can be maximal:

```
2.147.483.647
```

which is smaller than your int :
 4.253.726.258

Therefor it cannot fit in your `int`, you either need to stick to `long` or update your Java to version 8 and make an unsigned int.

What happens with conversion is that after 2.147.483.647, the count continues starting from the minimal number `(-2.147.483.647)` and finally giving you `-41241038` which is `-2.147.483.647+ (4.253.726.258 - 2.147.483.647)`